# categorical variables in factorial design

Tags: categorical-data, experiment-design

One dependent variable, One independent continuous variable and One independent categorical variable (two levels only). Factorial design is easy except I don't know how to add center points. I am planning to have -1 and +1 , representing low and high, but I can't add a zero 0 for the center point because the categorical variable has two levels only. How should I do it?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all... what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of adding center points to factorial designs is to look at possible nonlinearity.  With a categorical variable with 2 levels there are no issues of nonlinearity to look for, so it is not needed there.  If you are still interested in the non linearity of the continuous variable then you could do 2 center points with 0 for the continuous and -1, and 1 for the categorical variable.  So instead of a (0,0) center point you would have a (0,-1) and a (0,1) center point.